# Google Cast audio mirroring

Tags: android, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am looking into Google Cast for my Android app as I use AirPlay for my iOS app. Overall, the setup seems overly complicated. I happen to use Exoplayer, but in a bit off-label manner with multiple players potentially instantiated at once.

For this I am hoping to find a method to 'mirror' the audio similar to AirPlay (and what the Google Home app does). In iOS there is the `AVRoutePickerView()` that handles this.

For the life of me i can't seem to find any Google equivalent. Any advice would help.

Thanks!